# Codeception\Extension\RunProcess not starting processes

Tags: php, yii2, codeception

**PROBLEM:**

Yesterday Codeception introduced new extension which should help with starting/stopping Selenium Server, Chrome Driver, etc (more [here](http://codeception.com/07-11-2017/drive-your-browser-with-codeception.html)). However, even it shows that processes are starting - they're actually not.

**acceptance.suite.yml**

```
class_name: AcceptanceTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - WebDriver:
            url: http://127.0.0.1:8080/
            browser: chrome
        - Yii2:
            part: orm
            entryScript: index-test.php
            cleanup: false
extensions:
    enabled:
        - Codeception\Extension\RunProcess:
            - java -jar /home/tajgeer/.executables/bin/selenium-server.jar
            - php /home/tajgeer/Repozytoria/Yii2/yii serve
```

**output:**

```
Acceptance Tests (5)

  [RunProcess] Starting java -jar /home/tajgeer/.executables/bin/selenium-server.jar
  [RunProcess] Starting php /home/tajgeer/Repozytoria/Yii2/yii serve

E AboutCest: Ensure that about works 
E ContactCest: Ensure that contact page works 
E ContactCest: Contact form can be submitted 
E HomeCest: Ensure that home page works 
E LoginCest: Ensure that login works 

  [RunProcess] Stopping php /home/tajgeer/Repozytoria/Yii2/yii serve
  [RunProcess] Stopping java -jar /home/tajgeer/.executables/bin/selenium-server.jar
```

**example error:**

```
[ConnectionException] Can't connect to Webdriver at http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub. Please make sure that Selenium Server or PhantomJS is running.
```

I've already tried to set o+x permissions on both execs - didn't change anything. When I'm trying to run both tools by using entered commands - everything works well.

Could anyone point out what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

Actually... I've solved it on my own. I've forgot about `sleep` (processes didn't even had a chance to run as tests were very quick). I've changed `acceptance.suite.xml` to following:

```
class_name: AcceptanceTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - WebDriver:
            url: http://127.0.0.1:8080/
            browser: chrome
        - Yii2:
            part: orm
            entryScript: index-test.php
            cleanup: false
extensions:
    enabled:
        - Codeception\Extension\RunProcess:
            0: java -jar /home/tajgeer/.executables/bin/selenium-server.jar
            1: php /home/tajgeer/Repozytoria/Yii2/yii serve
            sleep: 5
```

Comment: Have tried but its not working. Is there any other solution for the same issue.

Comment: Thanks! sleep work for me. it was mentioned in [the document](https://codeception.com/extensions#runprocess)